# In “The One” (2001), how much did one alter’s death affect those that were still alive?

Tags: the-one

It’s shown in the film that Yulaw decided to hunt down his alter selves after the very first of them was killed during his service in [“Multiverse Authority” (MVA).](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GuardianOfTheMultiverse)

1. How much more powerful did that first alter’s life force make him?
2. How much more powerful (compared to their initial state) were Gabriel Yulaw and Gabriel Law during their confrontation? and—
3. How powerful would Yulaw become if he managed to kill all 124 of his alter selves?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first the build-ups in power would be incremental for the surviving versions of Yulaw because the power of the killed selves would get equally split among all the versions that remained. For instance, when the very first alter was killed, each of the remaining 124 selves became only .8% stronger than before.

The first noticeable hallmark can be drawn when 25 of his selves were killed — or only 100 remained. By this point each of the remaining selves have become ×1.25 times as powerful as they were when all 125 of the selves were still alive. Similarly, they’ve passed the ×2.5 mark compared to their original power when 75 of the selves got killed (50 vessels remaining), and so on — the less surviving alters remained the quicker power accumulation happened.

[image: picture of spreadsheet]

[*view full spreadsheet*](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M_XyrJHXk3H1EkVtEu1CmFY5xGH-uIFM9Aq56Bqary4/edit#gid=740268191)

So by the point Yulaw killed all other vessels except Law, they both were ×62.5 as powerful (had that much life force). And if Yulaw managed to kill Law as well that’d’ve doubled his power and made him ×125 as powerful as he originally was (when all his alter-selves were yet alive).

Comment: For me the question isn't "how much of their essence did he get" but rather "how did that essence transfer manifest itself". Is there a discernible difference in power between 117 and 118?

Comment: You're assuming that the life-essence was transferred equally. Is there anything in the film or bonus materials that confirms that?

Comment: (Re: C1) The film doesn’t say much on the issue other than Yulaw’s own remark regarding the noticeable change after the first alter’s death (hence my question). But I reckon if the MVA were to replicate Yulaw’s situation in an experimental environment, they’d get some differences from their test subjects between when 117 vessels were dead (alive) and when 118 were. E.g. at the point of 117 dead vessels each remaining one had ×15.625 life force, while at 118 dead vessels they had ×17.857. So if the subjects were to repeatedly punch a power-measuring device, the results would be different.

Comment: (Re: C2) The assumption is based on that not only both Yulaw and Law were getting stronger after other vessels’ deaths, but Law was also able to fight Yulaw on equal terms even though he had never killed any vessels himself (which renders Highlander-style power transfer invalid, for instance). IIRC, vessel #3 (the prisoner) was also stronger than normal — his punch/kick deformed a prison cell’s steel bars.